# How to suppress "unused variable" warnings in Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, variable-assignment, pydev

How to suppress "unused variable" warnings in Eclipse/PyDev

When I'm working with functions that return tuples, I often only need one of the values, but still want to assign to multiple variables. I would like to be able to temporarily turn this warning off so I can zero in on more serious issues. Then, I can turn it back on when doing more of a final check.

If you're wondering why I would do this deliberately, it's just for readability. Say a function returns a tuple of tuples, several parts of my code might work with the third value like this:

```
label, content = myfunc()[2]
```

At times, I may only be interested in the 'content' piece, but I find this...

```
tmp, content = myfunc()[2]
```

...to be more parallel (and thus more readable) than this:

```
content = myfunc()[2][1]
```

If there's a better way to do this simply without assigning to a disposable unused variable, feel free to provide that as an answer.

```
>>> myfunc()[2]
('lab', 'val')
>>> , v = myfunc()[2]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> tmp, v = myfunc()[2]
>>>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you don't need the value of a variable, assign it to the special variable `_`.

As far as Python is concerned, there is actually nothing special about `_`; it's just another legal identifier name like any other.

However, for most "lint"-style tools (hopefully including PyDev)—and, more importantly, human readers—it has the special meaning that "I don't need this variable, I'm only putting something here because the API/syntax/whatever requires it". Which means they won't warn you for not using it.

So:

```
_, content = myfunc()[2]
```

And yes, you are right that this is often more readable than `myfunc()[2][1]`. Not only that, but it helps you catch a few more errors—if `myfunc()[2]` doesn't have exactly two members, the tuple assignment will throw, but the `[1]` won't.

Very, very rarely, this is not a good idea because the value is something that you want to be garbage collected as soon as possible, and binding it to `_` instead of just not binding it at all (e.g., via `[2][1]`) delays that.

More seriously, this does conflict with a different idiom that also makes special use of `_`: Code that uses `gettext` for internationalization typically does:

```
import gettext
_ = gettext.gettext
```

Or, equivalently:

```
from gettext import gettext as _
```

Obviously you can't use `_` as both the gettext shortcut and the meaningless identifier. (You *could* actually get away with it, because the `gettext` meaning is bound at module-global level, and the meaningless identifier should only be used inside function bodies… but still, it's a very bad idea to try, because at some point you will end up using the `gettext` `_` in a function after you've assigned a local value that shadows it.) Nothing's forcing you to use `_` in either case—but if you use anything else, you are likely to confuse readers (and possibly the same linting tool you're looking to pacify in the first place). So, you have to decide which one is more important to you in any given project. (And usually, if you're using `gettext`, that's going to be the more important one.)

If you're repeatedly calling `myfunc` and disposing of some of the values, you might want to consider writing a wrapper function:

```
def mywrapperfunc():
    _, content = myfunc()[2]
    return content
```

Then your code can just do:

```
content = mywrapperfunc()
```

This has a number of advantages:

- It's obviously easier to read than anything that requires you to remember that you want the second half of a tuple which is in index 2 of the sequence that's returned by `myfunc`.
- It gives you a place to put a nice name (hopefully nicer than `mywrapperfunc`) and/or comments/docstrings, in case it isn't trivial.
- It means that if you later change `myfunc` so the value you want is now in index 3 instead of 2, and the second member of a 3-element tuple instead of a 2-element tuple, you only need to change `mywrapperfunc` instead of 20 different lines of code.
- It also means that if you later want to use a conflicting `_` idiom (e.g., to i18n your code with `gettext`), you only need to change it in one place.

One side note: In the interactive interpreter, `_` *does* have a special meaning: it's bound to the result of the last interactive command. But that doesn't mean you can't use `_` in the interactive interpreter. (In fact, it's even better there, because anything you stash there is immediately overwritten, so the very rare GC problem doesn't come up.)

Comment: `_` is used by `gettext`, so might not always be a great choice if your app is international

Comment: @gnibbler: Good point. Actually, `_` isn't actually used by `gettext`, but it's idiomatic to do `_ = gettext.gettext` or equivalent, which is almost the same thing. Anyway, you obviously can't use `_` as the meaningless identifier if you do that. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks for giving such a complete explanation! And now that sid16rgt has directed me to the configurable and informative setting dialog, I see the defaults will ignore _ or dummy or even _drop, or I can tweak the settings for something homegrown like drop.

Answer (score 24):

Add the comment `#@UnusedVariable` to the end of the line.

Every warning in PyDev has a similar deactivation comment. Use Quick Fix to discover them (place the cursor in the warning and press Ctrl+1), or refer to these lines from the [PyDev source code](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev.ast/src/org/python/pydev/ast/analysis/IAnalysisPreferences.java):

```java
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNUSED_IMPORT = "@UnusedImport";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNUSED_WILD_IMPORT = "@UnusedWildImport";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNUSED_VARIABLE = "@UnusedVariable";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE = "@UndefinedVariable";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_DUPLICATED_SIGNATURE = "@DuplicatedSignature";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_REIMPORT = "@Reimport";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNRESOLVED_IMPORT = "@UnresolvedImport";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_NO_SELF = "@NoSelf";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNDEFINED_IMPORT_VARIABLE = "@UndefinedVariable";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_UNUSED_PARAMETER = "@UnusedVariable";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_NO_EFFECT_STMT = "@NoEffect";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_INDENTATION_PROBLEM = "@IndentOk";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_ASSIGNMENT_TO_BUILT_IN_SYMBOL = "@ReservedAssignment";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_PEP8 = "@IgnorePep8";
public static final String MSG_TO_IGNORE_TYPE_ARGUMENTS_MISATCH = "@ArgumentMismatch";
```

Comment: The other approaches strike me as more convenient/transparent, but this is definitely a nice thing to know about Eclipse warnings. Thanks! (+1)

Answer (score 6):

Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis , "Unused" tab

Find the setting the for

*Don't report unused variable if name starts with: (comma separated)*

and then use one of the prefixes on this list, or add another prefix.

For example, if you have a throwaway variable "tmp" in the following code:

```
tmp, content = myfunc()[2]
```

and you have '_' on your list of prefixes to ignore, then convert "tmp" to "_tmp" like this:

```
_tmp, content = myfunc()[2]
```

Your error will go away.  I think this is a more readable solution than just using '_', as suggested by @abarnert, and it also avoids the complications of conflicting with translation.

Answer (score 3):

I run into this some times when I use a feature similar to the one you describe when a tuple is returned. You can globally set warning levels for the code analysis of PyDev in the Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis section. In Code Analysis in the Unused tab, there is an option to set the warning level for "Unused variable" as well as other occurrences.

Comment: That's really not a good solution. The warning is there for a good reason. In Python, it's very easy to write something like `foobra = func()` when you meant `foobar = func()`, so instead of updating `foobar` you end up creating another variable. This kind of problem is maddening to chase down. But if you never create unused variable names intentionally, a linter can catch these and similar problems for you (because they are equivalent to creating unused variable names accidentally). So, unless you're dealing with a large body of code that can't be fixed, leave the warning and fix your code.

Comment: I agree that typographical errors are easy to create and suppressing warnings like that have their drawbacks. I often find myself expanding variables from returns to keep the other variables in a state where I can mentally follow what I get back. Sometimes I use them. Sometimes not. For this reason, I leave my warnings on but others, like the OOP, might want to disable them. All I wanted to do was impart how.

Comment: Thanks (+1)--the various settings in Eclipse are a bit scattered, so I hadn't noticed this section under Window, Preferences. That same dialog also has a way to disable warnings for specific variable names, which is even better than temporarily turning the warnings off; the default is: "dummy, _, unused".

Comment: I meant to say that the default is variable names that *start with*: "dummy, _, unused".

Comment: This is excellent for some cases, I am using cython and keep gettings {duplicate signature} warnings, very annoying if it weren't for this fix!!

Answer (score -1):

Or, you can suppress a given warning in Eclipse in *any* language (including Python) using an extra plugin.
http://suppresswarnings.drupalgardens.com

Also avaible on the marketplace:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/marker-manager