# How to ignore rogue PyDev "error"

Tags: eclipse, jython, pydev

Doesn't seem to be answered here: [How to suppress "unused variable" warnings in Eclipse/PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944234/how-to-suppress-unused-variable-warnings-in-eclipse-pydev)

I am using Jython in Eclipse (Luna).

The problem comes with the following line:

```
p = runtime.exec( command )
```

This `exec` method is simply a method of `java.lang.Runtime`.  But PyDev gives me a red circle with a cross in the middle.  The words are

> Encountered "exec" at line ... Was expecting ... ...

I can find absolutely no way to turn this bleeping "helpful" "error message" off.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone grinding their teeth over this one: workaround found on source forge:

```
    exc = getattr(java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime(), 'exec')
    p = exc( command )
```